# In Python, how can I get the name of the function passed to my decorator with parameters?

Tags: python, methods, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to create a decorator that will validate if the parameter exist and retrieve the name of the method that is decorated.

I was able to access the name of the method in my second layer of the function but not the first.

For example, I have this decorator

```
def p_decorate(name, *a, **k):
    print(name + ' is at object: ')
    print a #I would like to get the method object here
    def fn(*a, **k)
        print a #object prints here instead
    return fn
return p_decorate
```

I have this class I would like to decorate

```
class Person(object):
    @p_decorate('John')
    def get_fullnameobject(self):
        return self.name
```

I expect it to print:

```
John is at object: (<function get_fullnameobject at 0x000000003745A588>,)
(<function get_fullnameobject at 0x000000003745A588>,)
```

but the output is:

```
John is at object: ()
(<function get_fullnameobject at 0x000000003745A588>,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `p_decorate` is being *called* with only argument `John` (`*a` and `**k` both will be empty), hence you're getting an empty tuple for `a`.

Just to note, the returned `fn` callable is being called with the `get_fullnameobject` callable afterwards.

More importantly, your current implementation is incomplete as you can never call the method -- you need another closure to actually do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need another nested function to define a decorator that takes arguments.

```
def p_decorate(name):
    def _(f):
        print(name + ' is at object: ')
        print f
        def fn(*a, **k):
            # Do something, but ultimately you probably want to call f
            ...
        return fn
    return _
```

`p_decorate("John")` returns the actual decorator, which takes `get_fullnameobject` as its `f` argument and returns the new `fn` object to bind to `get_fullnameobject`. Without decorator syntax, the usage looks like

```
def get_fullnameobject(self):
    return self.name

get_fullnameobject = p_decorate("John")(get_fullnameobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `function.__name__` to get the name of the function. So in your case it would be:

```
print(name.__name__ + ' is at object: ')
```